Spherical Polar Rotations | Is $(\theta + \pi, \phi + \pi) $ the same as $ (\theta + \pi, 0)$?
Question: I'd like some clarity on whether or not I can describe a $180^\circ$ rotation in spherical polar coordinates as $(\theta + \pi, \phi + \pi)$ affecting only the angles $\theta$ from the vertical $z$ axis and the azimuthal $\phi$.
I am modelling an isotropic photon source placed between two detectors.
The simulation deals with photon states of the form $((x, y, z), (\theta, \phi), \gamma)$ and samples hitpoints on the detector faces.
First, I sample a hitpoint on one detector then 'reflect' the coordinates to get the other detector's hitpoint.
My trouble is that upon applying a position update on the 'reflected' photon $(x', y', z')$ += $r (\cos{\phi'} \sin{\theta'} \;, \sin{\phi'} \sin{\theta'} \;, \cos{\theta'} )$
the resulting position is definitely not colinear.
I have attached a sketch of the coordinate system and a simulation of ~500 such updates.
Note: I can fix the problem by defining the direction 'reflection' as $(\theta', \phi') = (\theta + \pi, \phi + 0)$ (See ideal situation.) but I don't see why this should work, as rotating $\theta$ by $\pi$ gets me where I want to be, however $\phi$ would also need to rotate by $\pi$ for the coordinate to make sense?
